# How to empty textbox befor ModalPopupExtender show?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

My code is to insert the text from textbox, I did my code well but I want to empty the textbox before ModalPopupExtender show.  I did my code but It didn't work.

```
 protected void Btn_monthlyemployee_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    var Comment = (TextBox)((ImageButton)sender).Parent.FindControl("txt_monthlyemployee");

    ftier.Addcomment(LblMonthlyPID.Text, LoggedUserID, txt_monthlyemployee.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, false);

    Comment.Text = string.Empty;
    ModelExtenderPost.Show();


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have provided enough information although i am giving you some good techniques to resolve this

Your code should be work i don't know why its not working

You can have a jquery method

when your button clicked

```
$('#idofmonthlyeployeed').click(function()
{
      $('#commentboxid').val('');
      return false;   
});
```

You can see working example here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/PHX2Y/)

Or you can have a **update panel** issue if you don't have triggered button of your ***idofmonthlyeployeed***

So please add trigger of ***idofmonthlyeployeed***

I hope this will help you regards.....:)